# Table to domain giving ERROR 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, error-999999, domains

I am getting an Error while trying to execute "table to a domain".

The domain is "Nednaam":

[image]

The table is a .xls file, named "NedFlora", also a tekst file and looks like this:

[image]

My input:

[image]

My output:

[image]

What did go wrong? There are no double value's in the table.

Comment: I would try converting the excel to a filgeodatabase table and then try again with this as input

Comment: The GP tool is asking for the fieldname in your table (XLS) for the code and description. You don't have a header on your column that can be used as a field name...another reason to convert to a table.